# Enviar arquivo html para FTP - Python 3.6

Tags: python

desculpe a pergunta de leigo mas já pesquisei em todo lugar sem encontrar uma saída. Tenho o código abaixo e estou tentando enviar os arquivos diretamente para o FTP (inicialmente queria fazer isso sem ter que salvar localmente, mas devido a dificuldade em fazer estou partindo para outra ideia). Este código está funcionando perfeitamente até salvar os arquivos localmente mas a partir do `ftp.storlines` dá o seguinte erro: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'". Alguém pode ajudar?

```
from dominate import document
from dominate.tags import *
from ftplib import FTP
import getpass

psw = getpass.getpass('Digite sua senha: ')
ftp = FTP('sasasa.com.as')
ftp.login('usr', psw)
ftp.cwd('sasasa.com.as/cdc/sds')

border = "1"

for index, row in UltimaCotacao.iterrows():
    h = html()
    with h.add(body()):
        h1('Algo')
        with table().add(tbody()):
                l = tr()
                l += td('CNPJ: ', row['CNPJ_'])
                l += td('Valor da cota: ', row['VL_QUOTA'])
                l += td('Data: ', row['DT_COMPTC'])
    g = format_filename(row['CNPJ_'])+'.html'
    with open(g, 'w') as f:
        f.write(h.render())
    locpath = 'C:/Users/proj/'
    ftp.storlines('STOR ' + g, open(locpath+g, 'r'))
ftp.quit()
```

Desculpem se a pergunta não está clara mas é que, como disse, sou um leigo total em qualquer linguagem de programação (comecei há um mês por curiosidade e fascínio).
Abraços,

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com um pouco mais de pesquisa. Entendi que é preciso criar o arquivo antes de enviá-lo (achei que isto já estava sendo feito aqui `f.write(h.render())` mas de alguma forma não estava. Também teria que abri-lo como binário. Então criei um arquivo temporário para enviá-lo. Ficou assim:

```
g = format_filename(row['CNPJ_'])+'.html'
#with open(g, 'w') as f:
    #f.write(h.render())
#locpath = 'C:/Users/proj/'
arqtemp = open('temp.html', 'w').write(h.render())
ftp.storlines('STOR ' + g, open('arqtemp', 'rb'))
```